# My program works flawlessly in IntelliJ, but when I build it with Maven I get NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, intellij-idea, build

My main class is in LoginGUI, which looks like this (it's a way bigger class, but the other code is not relevant for my question):

```
package usermanagement;

public class LoginGUI extends JFrame {
private JPanel panel;
private JTextField usernameTextField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JButton loginButton;
private JButton registrationButton;
private JButton forgottenPaswordButton;
public static String loggedInUser;

public LoginGUI() {
    CourseDatabaseManager courseDatabaseManager = new CourseDatabaseManager();
    HibernateUtil.setup();
    UserDatabaseManager.initializeIfTableNotExists();

  
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("LoginPage");
    frame.setContentPane(new LoginGUI().panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

When I try to run the jar file that I got by building the project in Maven (it doesn't matter if I use Maven integration in IntelliJ or use the terminal, the results are the same) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at usermanagement.LoginGUI.<init>(LoginGUI.java:30)
    at usermanagement.LoginGUI.main(LoginGUI.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Line 30 is the first line in my constructor (the one with the CourseDatabaseManager), but I'm sure that's not the issue, because if I delete that line then it'll complain about the next one, and even if the constructor is completely empty it'll give me an error.

Line 93 is this line from the main method:    frame.setContentPane(new LoginGUI().panel);

I assume this is the one causing the issue, but I can't figure it out why, especially since it's working when I click on the run button in IntelliJ, so I'm not sure why wouldn't it work when building it with Maven? But I'm a beginner when it comes to Maven, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried looking up the issue, I found that I should change my pom file, which I did, but the issue still remains.
Here you can see my pom.xml (without the dependencies, I didn't want to post too much code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.whydontyouwork</groupId>
<artifactId>WorkPls</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>
                            usermanagement.LoginGUI
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Can anyone help how to build my project, so that I get a jar file that I can click and it'll simply start? I don't care if it's Maven or IntelliJ doing the hard work, but since I have a lot of dependenies I assume it has to be Maven. I appreciate any help, thank you!

I found this thread where they have some possible reasons / solutions, but I'm not sure where to start from here.

Comment: At a glance, looks like you're missing hibernate-core from your dependencies. https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha6/pom